# PyPDF2: Decrypt a File and Merge It With Other Members of a List of PDFs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, encryption, pypdf

I'm trying to automate some processes at work. I am able to merge PDFs from a list and able to take that merged PDF to create an encrypted PDF. Right now, I am stuck trying to take an existing encrypted PDF, decrypt it, and merge it with the other members of a list. Every time I decrypt and try to merge with a unencrypted PDF, My error message reads "File has not been decrypted." Below is my code up until where I need to merge encrypted and unencrypted PDFS.

Does PyPDF2 only allow you to **READ** encrypted PDFs using the decrypt method? Should I create a new list for encrypted PDFs and append to that? Is it possible to decrypt a PDF, copy its contents, and create a new unencrypted file? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
import os
import PyPDF2
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\######\Downloads')

#Here I merge Two dummy PDFs 
pdfs = ['Gateway Parking Form.pdf', 'sample.pdf']
merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
for pdf in pdfs:
    merger.append(pdf)
merger.write("result.pdf")
merger.close

#Here I copy the contents of the merged file to create a new encrypted PDF
pdfFile = open("result.pdf", "rb")
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdfReader.getPage(pageNum))
pdfWriter.encrypt("HelloDude")
resultPdf = open("result_Client.pdf", "wb")
pdfWriter.write(resultPdf)
pdfFile.close()
resultPdf.close()

#Here I WANT to decrypt the password-protected PDF and merge it with two dummy PDFs
pdfs = ['Gateway Parking Form.pdf', 'sample.pdf', "result_Client.pdf"]
for pdf in pdfs:
    pdfFile = open(pdf, "rb")
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
    writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    if reader.isEncrypted:
        reader.decrypt("HelloDude")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def decryption(input_name,output_name,password):
    pdfFile = open(input_name, "rb")
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
    writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    if reader.isEncrypted:
        reader.decrypt(password)
    for pageNum in range(reader.numPages):
        writer.addPage(reader.getPage(pageNum))
    resultPdf = open(output_name, "wb")
    writer.write(resultPdf)
    pdfFile.close()
    resultPdf.close()
```